# VB.Net Close two forms at once

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Kinda new to Visual Mode and need to get this simple thing to work for my coursework project.

The desired outcome is when the user tries to exit Form2, another form (FormCheck) will open asking the user if they are sure they want to leave, if they pick yes then both Form2 and FormCheck will close and Form1 will open. However when I try and do this, FormCheck will close and Form1 will open however Form2 will stay open behind Form1.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnYes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnYes.Click
        Dim NewForm As Form1
        NewForm = New Form1
        NewForm.Show()
        NewForm = Nothing
        Me.Close()
        Form2.Close()
```

As I said still new so would help if answer is as basic as possible.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you opening the form the same way you're opening Form1 in your example? If so, you instantiated a new Form2 and are trying to close the default instance. You would either need to pass a reference of your current instance of Form2 and close that instance or find and remove it from the Forms collection.

Comment: Just don't pester the user with useless dialogs.  Yes, he's sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find existing `Form2`.

```
'YOUR EXISTING CODE HERE
For Each frm as Form in Application.OpenForms
    If frm.Name="Form2"
        frm.Close()
    End If
Next
'CLOSE THIS FORM HERE
```

You should run this code before closing the current form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a property in Form2 that telling if the user click yes or no. According to his answer, you can close Form1 or not. Form2 will be closed once user click on yes or no anyway.

```
Public Partial Class Form1
    Inherits Form
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim form2 As New Form2()
        form2.ShowDialog()

        If form2.IsExitRequired Then
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Partial Class Form2
    Inherits Form
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Property IsExitRequired() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_IsExitRequired
        End Get
        Private Set
            m_IsExitRequired = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_IsExitRequired As Boolean

    Private Sub yesButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        IsExitRequired = True
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub noButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        IsExitRequired = False
        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You must close first the other form before closing the *current* form.

```
Form2.Close() 
Me.Close()
```